# How to reduce the size of a file describing a Deep Neural Network model?

Tags: xml, matlab, deep-learning, bigdata

We are training a deep neural network model on Matlab, and then export it to a model file in order to distribute it to the company's products.

Essentially, this file is supposed to contain meta data, plus a several **big** matrices.

At the moment, we use an **XML format** and the matrices' values are represented textually. **This yields a file that's ~30 MB in size**, and I'm looking for another format to drastically reduce that size.

I have total liberty to decide on the file format, as long as it's something that Matlab is capable for exporting.

Any ideas? Common industry practices in this case? Thanks!

Comment: Unclear. Reduce the size of the file in what context? You could gzip the file and probably get 70% reduction.  See https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/280657

Comment: The way I always do it is just writing it out as bytes into a binary file. This creates the smallest possible file without being lossy. I have never used Matlab before though so I couldn't tell you if it will work out or not.

Comment: I guess you need some standard thing... so maybe Excel's xls (`xlswrite` from MATLAB). Matlab's MAT file might be an option if other "company products" can read it.

Comment: Thanks for the responses all! @Jim Garrison, I want to reduce the file size by any means necessary. Trying to clarify: the 'input' of my problem are large data structures in Matlab. The output should be a single file contains that data and is bundled with various applications that need this data (and are written in other programming languages).

Comment: Since I suppose that this is a common problem in algorithms engineering, I was hoping there were industry-standard solutions for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having not found a better alternative, we decided to split up the model data to two files: An XML file containing only Meta Data, and a binary file which contains a binary serialization (in contrast of text serialization) of each matrix's values.

If anyone comes up with a suitable 3rd party tool / package or any less naive way of accomplishing this, please post here.